# Flot line chart getting hidden

Tags: css, flot, linechart, displayobject

If I try setting the `height` of the x-axis label, then the line chart( displayed using **Flot**) is getting hidden.
Why is this happening and what's the solution?

```
#placeholder .flot-text .xAxis .tickLabel{
    color: #74878B;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    position: absolute !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    z-index: 0;
    top:55px !important
}
```

Comment: You should post a link to a jsfiddle / codepen with the markup and css where we can see the problem, or at least post the code in your question - and also post something about what you have tried to solve the issue!

Comment: **http://jsfiddle.net/swetha/S6JEN/1/**

Since I ve mentiontioed height for xais label the graph is compressed, i dont want the graph to be compressed!!

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you set the height of a label?  Also, why are you using 'top' to manually position the labels, as opposed to just using position: 'top' in the axis options?

Comment: i want the labels to appear top of the graph so iam using top, i need to give them height so that i can put a right border for each month name which is as per the design.